# 2 bloc and 1 widget

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have widget (FirstWidget) and 2 providers to this widget on 2 different pages.

First screen:

```
BlocProvider<FirstBloc>(
   create: (context) => FirstBloc()
   child: FirstWidget(),
)
```

Second screen:

```
BlocProvider<SecondBloc>(
   create: (context) => SecondBloc()
   child: FirstWidget(),
)
```

How to manage specific bloc in this widget using e.g. blocbuilder?

For example on first screen I wanna use in this widget FirstBloc and on second screen SecondBloc but this widget is in one file. What should i write in BlocBuilder? I tried `BlocBuilder<dynamic, dynamic>` but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two widgets. One wich uses `BlocBuilder<FirstBloc, FirstState>` and a second widget, which uses `BlocBuilder<SecondBloc, SecondState>`.

You could also pull the `BlocBuilder` out of the widget and pass some values into the widget in order to build it dependently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        
BlocProvider<FirstBloc>(
   create: (context) => FirstBloc(),
BlocProvider<SecondBloc>(
   create: (context) => SecondBloc()
   
),
child: FirstWidget(),
      ],)
```